# Postgres - Append copy command to CSV File

Tags: shell, copy, append, psql

I use this command for copy data from table (inside .sql file).

```
copy(select index,codice_fiscale,campo1,campo2 from tmp_table) TO STDOUT (DELIMITER '|');
```

This command works for print on STDOUT but i must to copy the result in csv file, in append .

I use this command for run .sql file

```
psql -h $HOST -d $DB -U $USER -p $PORT -a -q -f $FILESQL;
```

If I use redirection (>>) in shell command, it prints all commands in sqlFile. I would just like the result of copy command.

Thanks in advance.

append copy command to file

Comment: Run the command from your shell and use ´>>` to append its stdout to the file of your choice.

Comment: i add '>>' at the bottom but not work

Comment: I don't see any shell command in your posting, so I can't say what you did wrong.

Comment: This comman is in .sql file that i execute with psql command. I use 
copy(select index,codice_fiscale,campo1,campo2 from tmp_table) TO STDOUT (DELIMITER '|') >> text.csv; but not work

Comment: Yes, and then show how you redirected the psql command. After all, you tagged the question _shell_, so at the very least show your shell command.

Comment: I use copy(select index,codice_fiscale,campo1,campo2 from tmp_table) TO STDOUT (DELIMITER '|') >> text.csv; inside .sql file. But not work

Comment: Of course it does not work. Why do you do it inside the sql file? My recommendation stated explicitly to do the redirection on the shell level. I don't say that it is **impossible** within PSQL (I don't know it well); perhaps there is a possibility to specify appending to a file name after `TO`, but this would then not be called _redirection_. My suggestion uses shell features, and since you tagged the question as _shell_, I assumed that you would be fine with such a solution.

Comment: i use redirection on psql command but other things are copied into file (query and other command in sql file)

Comment: It's pointless to continue this discussion, unless you edit your question and show the exact shell commands you are using.

Comment: _I use redirection (>>)_  There is no `>>` in your shell command.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for an answer to this and outputting to STDOUT and to a pipe all works, but I wound up figuring out a very simple solution.

Create a sql file that has a copy command in it and output to a temp file

> \copy (query of data you want to get) to '/usr/local/sbin/temp_file.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV

Then use a simple `cat` command to redirect that data to your aggregate file

> cat temp_file.csv >> aggregate_data_file.csv

From there you can get more data from another database by running the copy command and then using `cat` again to append to your aggregate file.